# How to Split pandas column and check values?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create new column in my dataframe based on the other column Values.

df:

```
  Id    Value
  0     L+N
  1     L+P+N
  2     L
  3     L+L+L
  4     G+G
  5     L+N
```

df_output:

```
  Id    Value   Value2
  0     L+N     L+N
  1     L+P+N   L+P+N
  2     L       L
  3     L+L+L   L
  4     G+G     G
  5     L+N     L+N
```

If Value column contains same letters L+L+L then Value2 would be L else there would be no change.

Comment: Little more details in the question would be really helpful. `check values` for what??

Comment: @ShubhamSharma sorry my bad... updated the question please check.

Comment: What if the value column contains `M+M+M`, do you still want to replace it with `M`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the items into a list, find the unique elements in list by [`pd.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html), and then join back the items by [`.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html), as follows:

```
df['Value2'] = df['Value'].str.split('+').map(pd.unique).str.join('+')
```

Result:

```
print(df)

    Id  Value Value2
0   0    L+N    L+N
1   1  L+P+N  L+P+N
2   2      L      L
3   3  L+L+L      L
4   4    G+G      G
5   5    L+N    L+N
```

Comment: You might consider [`pd.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) which not only doesn't require an additional import, but also "Uniques are returned in order of appearance. This does NOT sort. Significantly faster than numpy.unique." Which would ensure order is maintained as above _and_ be more performant.

Comment: @SeaBean this would be best answer if something like `L+L+G` is not present on the df, cuz then it would return `L+G`

Comment: @Yefet  I presumed OP want to remove duplicated letters from the string.  It could be a valid case of what you mentioned but in real life case should be much rarer use case.

Answer (score 1):

Dataframe :

```
    Value
0   L+L+L
1   L+G

df["Value2"] = df["Value"].str.split("+").apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(set(x)) ==1
                                                else "+".join(x) )
```

Output:

```
    Value   Value2
0   L+L+L   L
1   L+G     L+G
```

Answer (score 1):

try `str.split` `stack` and `groupby` `unique` to get the unique values.

```
df['col2'] = df['Value'].str.split('+',expand=True).stack()\
                       .groupby(level=0).agg('unique').agg('+'.join)

   Id  Value   col2
0   0    L+N    L+N
1   1  L+P+N  L+P+N
2   2      L      L
3   3  L+L+L      L
4   4    G+G      G
5   5    L+N    L+N
```